# Cant able to run Android app and error: Error retrieving parent for item error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

I recently installed eclipse and set up the libraries for android development, i just created a new android application from eclipse with configuration as 
minimum version as 2.2, target version as 4.1.2, compile version as 4.1.2. When i cleaned the project after creating it i was getting a lot of errors in the console as below

```
[Date - SwipingTabs] /home/user/workspace/appcompat_v7/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:117: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[Date - SwipingTabs] 
[Date - SwipingTabs] /home/user/workspace/appcompat_v7/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:155: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[Date - SwipingTabs] 
[Date - SwipingTabs] /home/user/workspace/appcompat_v7/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:157: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[Date - SwipingTabs] 
[Date - SwipingTabs] /home/user/workspace/appcompat_v7/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:158: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[Date - SwipingTabs] 
[Date - SwipingTabs] /home/user/workspace/appcompat_v7/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:156: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[Date - SwipingTabs] 
[Date - SwipingTabs] /home/user/workspace/appcompat_v7/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:153: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[Date - SwipingTabs] 
[Date - SwipingTabs] /home/user/workspace/appcompat_v7/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:154: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[Date - SwipingTabs] 
[Date - SwipingTabs] /home/user/workspace/appcompat_v7/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:192: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[Date - SwipingTabs] 
[Date - SwipingTabs] /home/user/workspace/appcompat_v7/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:194: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[Date - SwipingTabs] 
[Date - SwipingTabs] /home/user/workspace/appcompat_v7/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:195: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[Date - SwipingTabs] 
[Date - SwipingTabs] /home/user/workspace/appcompat_v7/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:193: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[Date - SwipingTabs] 
[Date - SwipingTabs] /home/user/workspace/appcompat_v7/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:190: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[Date - SwipingTabs] 
[Date - SwipingTabs] /home/user/workspace/appcompat_v7/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:191: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[Date - SwipingTabs]
```

I don't know why these errors are appearing and also i can't able to run the project.

My project properties are

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also i observed that when i created the project a new folder appcompat_7 folder was created in my workspace and it was with errors

Also when i opened the `MainActivity.java` there was an error at `R` saying that `R cannot be resolved to a variable`

can someone know how to solve these errors ?

Comment: while cleaning had you checked the menuitem "build automatically" also?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the last appcompat v21.

You have to compile your project with API21.